# Rails db association issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

This is my current table setup:

WINES
id...etc. etc.

AWARDS
id, wine_id, competition_id, medal_id, date, link

COMPETITIONS
id, name

MEDALS
id, type

Award > belongs_to :wine
Wine > has_many :awards, :autosave => true, :dependant => :destroy

That's all well and fine, but I'd like to be able to reference the 'name' and 'type' columns for each award's competition and medal.  Currently I can only see 'competition_id' and 'medal_id'...I'd like to be able to say '@wine.awards[0].medal' which would result in "Gold"...or even 'medal_type' for that matter.  How would I set up that association in my model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well, using this relation:

```
Award > belongs_to :medal
```

so you can say @wind.awards[0].medal.type and have "Gold" as result. Every relation must be defined, so you have also to add

```
 Award > belongs_to :competition
```

So you can to @wine.awards[0].competition.name

And also the backwards relation are important.

```
Competition > has_many :awards
Medals > has_many :awards
```

Comment: The belongs_to in the award model seems to have solved that issue, thanks!  However I don't see why it would make sense to use the has_many for the competition and medal models as they aren't meant to hold awards - they are simply meant to be a name/value pair.

Comment: Let's say you want to find all the wine that won at leas a gold medal. With the correct backward relation you can do Medal.find_by_type('gold').awards.collect(&:wine), for example!